# Two questions about casting objects in cpp

Tags: c++, casting

***Question A***

If I have two classes: "father", and "MyClassa" and I want to do this:

```
father* a;
MyClassa b;
a = &b;
((MyClassa *)a) - > b();
```

I can do the casting like in the sample above (`b()` is a function belonging to `MyClassa` class and not found in `father` class).

But when I do this:

```
father* a;
MyClassa b;
a = &b;
a = ((MyClassa *)a);
a->b();
```

It doesnt work for me and tells me that he `b()` function not exist in that class (like the casting didn't work).

What are the differences between these two code samples actually and what is causing this differences?

***Question B***

When I use 'dynamic_cast' to cast a father to be a child like this:

```
Father * fp= new Father;
Child * cp = dynamic_cast<Child *> fp;
```

It returns me a '0' value to the pointer.
But when I do the same with reference:

```
Father & fp= new Father;
Child & cp = dynamic_cast<Child &> fp;
```

It raises an error 'bad casting'.

Why is there a difference?

Comment: Give us a more complete example. How does the class declaration of `MyClassa` look like?

Comment: Show a [MCVE] please.

Comment: These questions are unrelated, please separate them.

Comment: Hints to find the solution yourself: `a = <something>` does not change the type which is assigned to `a`; references can never be `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line

```
a = ((MyClassa *)a);
```

the term gets casted to `MyClassa*` but then back to `father*` (in the assignment) so you end up with a `father*`.

Regarding your second question: It's impossible to cast the reference from the father to the child, and also "wrong" in terms of polymorphism

Comment: Thanks. regarding the second question - so why when I do thw casting from a father pointer to a child pointer (not a reference, but a pointer.) its returns me '0' value and not throwing also an casting error?

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast: 
If the cast fails and new_type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type. If the cast fails and new_type is a reference type, it throws an exception that matches a handler of type std::bad_cast.